# Linq- preferable value in select

Tags: c#, linq

If I have the following model:

```
Public class Person {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
  public int Salary {get; set;}
}
```

and I have a list of Persons, `List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();`

Now I want the most common salary of Managers, if none exists I want most common salary of MiddleManagers.

I tried the following:

```
int salary= persons.Where(x => x.Type=="Manager" || x.Type=="MiddleManager")
                    .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .Select(x => x.Key)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

but that would return the most common salary among both Managers and MiddleManagers, is there a way to achieve the above without going to:

```
 int salary= persons.Where(x => x.Type=="Manager")
                        .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                        .Select(x => x.Key)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
if(salary==0)
 salary= persons.Where(x => x.Type=="MiddleManager")
                        .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                        .Select(x => x.Key)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Why would I want to avoid the above? because I have the same logic for many properties.

Comment: You can order by Type before you order by Count. That'll give you the managers first, if you include the Type in your GroupBy.

Comment: "I have the same logic for many properties." how same is the same logic? different properties of the type `Person` ?

Comment: Could type be `enum`, this will make your life easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using C# local functions:

```
ILookup<string, Person> personsByType = persons.ToLookup(person => person.Type);

double getSalary(string type)
{
     return personsByType[type]
              .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
              .Select(x => x.Key)
              .FirstOrDefault();
}

double salary= getSalary("Manager");
if (salary == 0)
{
    salary = getSalary("MiddleManager");
}
```

Note that if you get a 0 salary only if there are no people of a given type since I don't think someone can have a 0 salary. So you could do:

```
double? getSalary(string type)
{
   IEnumerable<Person> selectedPeople = personsByType[type];

   return selectedPeople.Any() ? selectedPeople
                                  .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                                  .Select(x => x.Key)
                                  .First()
                               : null;
}

double? salary= getSalary("Manager");
if (!salary.HasValue)
{
    salary = getSalary("MiddleManager");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check whether [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) items exist that match the first criterion and assign the `Type` to a string variable which will be used in the query:

```
string property = persons.Any(x => x.Type == "Manager") ? "Manager" : "MiddleManager";

int salary = persons.Where(x => x.Type == property)
                .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

a half way general method for exactly this grouping logic in `List<Person>` could look like this:

```
public int mostCommonSalary(List<Person> collection, params string [] types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (collection.Any(x => x.Type == type))
        {
            return collection.Where(x => x.Type == type)
                    .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .Select(x => x.Key)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }   

    // nothing found
    return -1;
}
```

you can use it then with as many types as you want. The first match of it will be returned:

```
int salary = mostCommonSalary(persons,  "Manager", "MiddleManager", "MicroManager", "NanoManager");
```

You could get it even more general or generic by passing the property that you would like to have filtered:

```
public int mostCommonSalaryGeneral<T>(List<Person> collection, 
                                      Func<Person, T> filterFunc,  params T[] types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (collection.Any(x=> filterFunc(x).Equals(type)))
        {
            return collection.Where(x=> filterFunc(x).Equals(type))
                    .GroupBy(pr => pr.Salary)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .Select(x => x.Key)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    // nothing found
    return -1;
}
```

This way you can filter by a chosen property and call the method like this:

```
int salary = mostCommonSalaryGeneral(persons, p => p.Type, "Manager", "MiddleManager", "MicroManager", "NanoManager");
int salary = mostCommonSalaryGeneral(persons, p => p.Name, "Max", "Maxine", "Masud");
int salary = mostCommonSalaryGeneral(persons, p => p.SomeID, 1234, 3456);
```

Comment: You first step in this answer is correct and great. If you had stopped there it would be +1. Great you added generalisation too (implied in the question). However I think in  your last one specifically fails to answer the original questions since `mostCommonSalaryGeneral(persons, p => p.Type, "Manager", "MiddleManager", "MicroManager", "NanoManager");` mixes up manager types salaries, exactly what the question wanted to avoid?

Comment: @Martino The last version yields exactly the same results as the first. It follows the same filter routine like the first; same where clause. Can you explain why you see there a difference and how it mixes up the manager types?

Comment: Yup you are right! Need my morning coffee before I comment! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple loop over the 2 types, with the Linq query in the loop body, or build a function around the Linq query and call it with different types. Example:

```
var salary = GetSalary(persons, "Manager");
if (salary == 0) salary = GetSalary(persons, "MiddleManager");
```

Comment: Simple but I guess the OP wants to avoid multiple loops